# Undefined property when using cacheMethod = db

Tags: cache, error-message

What can the issue be here? I have no clue.

Config settings are like this:

```
'cacheMethod'           => "db",
'cacheDuration'         => 'P2M', /*2 months*/
```

**Undefined property: Craft\WebApp::$db**

```
/var/www/www_cmgg_cmgg_be/craft/app/services/CacheService.php(46)

34         switch (craft()->config->get('cacheMethod'))
35         {
36             case CacheMethod::APC:
37             {
38                 $this->_cacheComponent = new ApcCache();
39                 break;
40             }
41 
42             case CacheMethod::Db:
43             {
44                 $this->_cacheComponent = new DbCache();
45                 $this->_cacheComponent->gCProbability = craft()->config->get('gcProbability', ConfigFile::DbCache);
46                 $this->_cacheComponent->cacheTableName = craft()->db->getNormalizedTablePrefix().craft()->config->get('cacheTableName', ConfigFile::DbCache);
47                 $this->_cacheComponent->autoCreateCacheTable = true;
48                 break;
49             }
50 
51             case CacheMethod::EAccelerator:
52             {
53                 $this->_cacheComponent = new EAcceleratorCache();
54                 break;
55             }
56 
57             case CacheMethod::File:
58             {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The client was using something called Samba Share on their server and that didn't work well with permissions. They changed servers and it was solved.